# Click event for specific cell in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, datagridview, click

I have a cell in a datagridview its located at the 8th row 2nd column That cell and that cell only if clicked I want to show as save as dialoguebox but I can actually get a click event happening for a specific cell how do I do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In you dataGridView Event "DataGridView1_CellClick" add this code :

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 And e.RowIndex = 8 Then
        'Do any thing

        MsgBox("yes" + DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: a bit late, but lets say I want to call this event from another event (lets say a DataBindingComplete) event so that I can automatically click on the first element of the freshly loaded DGV how would I call the cell click event?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

''Code HERE............

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_pos.CellContentClick
      Dim i As Integer

      With DataGridView_pos
          If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
              i = .CurrentRow.Index

              txt_update_detail_id.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("id").Value.ToString

          End If
      End With

  End Sub
'txt_update_detail_id.Text Output value by id (Mysql database)
'Is work
```