# how to display another form when a specific datagridview cell is click in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to display a form (ex. Search Form) if a certain cell is clicked, but I don't know where to begin when I tried some eventhandlers like cellclick, cellcontentclick etc. and I failed. It all resulted to an unhandled exception error.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3eMb.png)

For example if I click the cell in column code a form should be displayed.

Is there any way to accomplished my desired output?

any suggestions is appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event for specific cell in datagridview vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845456/click-event-for-specific-cell-in-datagridview-vb-net)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469518) out.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Now I have something to start with. thanks!